# Error when adding multiple paths in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

When I add mulitple path in my code, it gives error.

**Code**

> views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Nikhil")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("About Nikhil")
```

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index')
    path('about',views.about,name='about')
    #error:Above line is giving error
]
```

when I run the code for 1 path,it does not give any error,
but when multiple path is added it givens error

Comment: What is the error you get? Can you add it to your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlpatterns` is a list, so you need to add a comma after each `path` entry

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('about',views.about,name='about'),
    #error:Above line is giving error
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`path('about',views.about,name='about')` in this line should be `'about/'` and there should be a comma after each `path` so the correct code would be

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('about/',views.about,name='about')
    #error:Above line is giving error
]
```

Answer (score 0):

@nikhil_2001

in your path

urls.py

```
path('',views.index,name='index')
```

the path doesn't have a comma at the end of it, you need to add a comma at the end of each path or the program won't work

Comment: mark an answer if it solved the problem to let people know it worked for you :)